# My pytorch model is not updating its parameters

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

i have created a pytorch model i am currently new to using pytorch.
My aim is to build a face recognition system. give 2 images as input to model and have vector representation of them after which a sigmoid neuron which will then give output in 0 (if not same person) else 1 (if same person).
Here is my model.

```
class SamModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3, stride=1)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(38*38*32, 128)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(128*2, 1)
        
    def forward_one(self, inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = self.lin1(x)
        x = F.leaky_relu(x)
        
        return x
    
    def forward(self, input1, input2):
        output1 = self.forward_one(input1)
        output2 = self.forward_one(input2)
        
        output = torch.concat([output1, output2], dim=1)
        output = self.lin2(output)
        output = F.sigmoid(output)
        
        return output
```

here is my model and optimizer

```
model = SamModel()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
```

and here are my training steps

```
for i in range(5):
    
    model.zero_grad()
    
    outputs = model(images1, images2)
    loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(outputs, y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    print(loss)
```

i tried changing the loss function but the parameters still do not update i get a constant loss it did not decrease.
here is the output

```
tensor(49., grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward0>)
tensor(49., grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward0>)
tensor(49., grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward0>)
tensor(49., grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward0>)
tensor(49., grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyBackward0>)
```

please can someone tell where i am wrong

after doing this much i was expecting the loss to decrease but it is constant means for some reason my model is not training.

Comment: try scaling your data and playing with learning rate

Comment: you have `model.zero_grad()`, I could be wrong but shouldn't that be `optimizer.zero_grad()` instead? That's at least how I usually do it.

Comment: i tried using both `model.zero_grad()` and `optimizer.zero_grad()` i guess my parameters in layers before torch.concat() are not updating since i tried printing them and they did not change only the parameters of the layer `self.lin2()` are updating other are not.

Comment: @ParthGupta Along with using `optimizer.zero_grad()`, I think that most likely means something is not right in `forward_one`. Try printing `x` at each line to make sure they look like what you want them to.

Comment: There isn't any wrong in your code, you just need to scale your inputs. I tried your code with random inputs, and it works. It would be better, if you could share the inputs.

Comment: Yes thankyou i you are correct the problem was with scaling inputs i scaled them and it now works correnctly